# Getting just the data from a selected column range

Tags: vba, excel

The user has to select a column(s) of data that is then used in an array in my vba code. If the user selects the column letter, he gets the whole column, data and blank cells. Is there a way, other than going through the array, an item at a time, to get just the data in that column, when the whole column is selected.

I have code like this:

```
Set user_range = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection
points = user_range.value

i = LBound(points, 1)

count = UBound(points, 1) - i + 1
```

I appreciate any help anyone can give!

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible background.

**1)** if `Selection` could contain *only constants*:

```
Dim user_range As Range
Dim points
On Error Resume Next
Set user_range = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not user_range Is Nothing Then points = user_range.Value
```

---

**2)** if `Selection` could contain *only formulas*:

```
Dim user_range As Range
Dim points
On Error Resume Next
Set user_range = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not user_range Is Nothing Then points = user_range.Value
```

---

**3)** if `Selection` could contain *both constants and formulas*:

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, user_range As Range
Dim points

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Set rng2 = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng1 Is Nothing And Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    Set user_range = Union(rng1, rng2)
ElseIf Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Set user_range = rng1
ElseIf Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    Set user_range = rng2
End If

If Not user_range Is Nothing Then points = user_range.Value
```

---

**4)** if you want to cut unused part of selection (the part that was never used), you can try following code (but in many cases it's unreliable, since `UsedRange` contains all cells that was used at least once, e.g. if you delete value from cell, this cell would be empty but still part of `UsedRange`):

```
Dim user_range As Range

Set user_range = Intersect(UsedRange, Selection)
If Not user_range Is Nothing Then points = user_range.Value
```